# Как отловить деление на 0 в try/catch

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Вот есть к примеру такой скрипт:

```
try {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 3/a;
    $("#result").append(b);
} catch (e) {
    $("#result").append("Error Message: " + e.message);
    $("#result").append("<br />");
    $("#result").append("Error Code: ");
    $("#result").append(e.number & 0xFFFF)
    $("#result").append("<br />");
    $("#result").append("Error Name: " + e.name);
}
```

Результат его выполнения — надпись `Infinity` в диве `#result`.

Подскажите, как заставить оператор try обработать деление на 0 как ошибку? А лучше — чтобы во всей программе это считалось ошибкой.

Comment: В Javascript деление на 0 нормальная вполне операция. Можно выбросить свое исключение.  

    if (b == Infinity) throw new Error("Деление на 0");

Comment: pfff

    var result = .....;
    if(isFinite(result)) {
      // ...
    }

Comment: Ох уж эти костыли. А вот еще что — Math.sqrt(-5). Там NaN возвращает. Прийдется все ифами обрабатывать...

Comment: @Zelta isFinite ваше все

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ага. И IsNaN :)

Comment: @Zelta достаточно только isFinite.

    isFinite(NaN) // -> false

А то, что вы называете хаком и страшно недовольны, например, в какой-то там Java, выглядит куда печальнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак не заставить, в JavaScript деление на ноль даёт бесконечность.

Ну кроме как `0/0`, которое дает `NaN` (хотя исключение и не отдает).

Просто добавьте проверку на `Infinity` и `NaN`.